In 1 Corinthians 7:2, why does Paul use two different words for “own”?
In 1 Corinthians 7:2, Paul uses two separate Greek words for “own.”
“But because of the temptation to sexual immorality, each man should have his own [idios] wife and each woman her own [heautou] husband.”
Do you think there is a reason why Paul uses separate terms, given that they both essentially mean the same thing?

You have it backwards. “His own” is τὴν ἑαυτοῦ, while “her own” is τὸν ἴδιον.

In fact, there is only one word in 1 Cor 7:2 that means "own" which is ἴδιον (idion).  Let me translate the verse very literally:

Because, however, the sexual immorality, each [man] the of himself wife
let have; and each [woman] the own husband let have.

In more idiomatic English I would render this (still literally)

However, because of sexual immorality, let each man have the wife of
himself; and let each woman have her own husband.

Thus, the adjective ἴδιον (idion) occurs only once.

In other words, there are two different Greek constructions, both of which it's natural to render as "his/her own" in English? This isn't at all an uncommon situation in translation.

@user111403 - that is correct.

Your answer is correct in a narrow sense, but the point of the question is why Paul doesn't refer to them the same. What distinction does he intend?

1 Cor. 7:2, 14:35; Eph. 5:22; Tit. 2:5; 1 Pet. 3:1, 5 > The aspect is submission.
